# Vue how to concat dynamic id with field from v-for loop + string?

Tags: dynamic, vue.js, vuejs2, concatenation

I have a v-for loop in my template like this :

```
<th v-for="(field, key) in lists[$route.params.model][$route.params.status].fields"
                        :key="key">
                        <div class="columnName">{{ field }}</div>
                        <div class="arrows">
                            <div class="arrow-up-icon" @click="getSearchResult(1, query, statusesIds,
                                lists[$route.params.model][$route.params.status].values[key], 'desc')"></div>
                            <div :id="here should me dynamic id" class="arrow-down-icon" @click="getSearchResult(1, query, statusesIds,
                                 lists[$route.params.model][$route.params.status].values[key], 'asc')"></div>
                        </div>
                    </th>
```

And now my problem is that i would like to have in my dynamic id ( for each button in my loop ) to be like this: :id="order_by"+{{filed}}  <-- this is from loop + {{key}}<-- this is from loop too. But I cannot to write this to work. I can't concat this to be a dynamic id. Can I do this in my tempplate where is my :id?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You don't need to use the template {{prop}}, just use plain JavaScript string concatenation.

```html
    <th v-for="(field, key) in lists[$route.params.model][$route.params.status].fields"
         :id="'order_by' + field"
         :key="key"
    >
                      
    </th>
```

[Using JavaScript Expressions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions)

Answer (score 4):

If you are generating a row by writing a template about each row. Then, I think this is the solution for you.

```
  <TradeTableItem
    v-for="(debtReserve, index) in debtReserves"
    :key="debtReserve.id"
    :debtReserve="debtReserve"
    :market="market"
    :id="'reserve' + index"
  ></TradeTableItem>
```

In the upper step, we generated an `id` for each `row`.

And, in TradeTableItem (your template where we are populating, the table rows), Write `id` as `:id="this.id"` where `this.id` is a part of props.

Hope this helps